# Look for value in another pandas dataframe and replace column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have the following dataframe:

```
Country Employee ID Location
CZ        1        WAREHOUSE
CZ        2        Warehouse
CZ        3        PlaNt
CZ        4        Car
DK        5        Car
DK        7 
ES        7        *
ES        8       Técnico
ES        3       Rádio
```

I need to search for the values added in "Location" column in the dataframe below (not considering if the value is capslock or not and disconsidering special non english characters punctuation such as in the example) considering its country and:

- if the "Location" value exists in that country on second dataframe, replace for that value.
- if the "Location" value do not exist in that country on second dataframe, replace for the first  value of the second dataframe
- Create a column named "Legacy Location" that, if "Location" was replaced, add previous Location Name to that column. if Location was not replaced, leave column blank. And, if "Location" was blank when doing the comparison, add the string "blank" to "Legacy Location" column.

This is the lookup dataframe:

```
Country Location name
CZ      Warehouse
CZ      Plant
DK      Car
DK      Plant
DK      Warehouse
ES      Tecnico
ES      Rádio
```

And that is the expected output:

```
Country Employee ID Location    Legacy Location
CZ         1        Warehouse   WAREHOUSE
CZ         2        Warehouse   
CZ         3        Plant       PlaNt
CZ         4        Warehouse   Car
DK         5        Car 
DK         7        Car         Blank
ES         7        Tecnico     *
ES         8        Tecnico     Técnico
ES         3        Rádio
```

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Thank you so much!

Comment: (1) Do you require a match on the Country column too? There's `CZ, Warehouse` and `DK, Warehouse` in the lookup data frame. (2) the `DK, 7` row has a blank location. Does it carry over the value of the previous row, or the previous row of the same country?

Comment: Your attempts to get at least some result are not visible.

Comment: Hello, thanks for clarifying. 1) yes the match should be combination of country and location 2) the row where it has a blank value location it would also take the first value of the lookup df of its respective country and in Legacy Location column it would add "blank" so I can identify it was previously blank. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `df` is the first dataframe and `lookup_df` is the lookup one, use this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

out = df.merge(lookup_df, on='Country', how='left')
out['Location_v2'] = out.apply(lambda x: x['Location name'][0] if str(x['Location']).title() not in x['Location name'] else str(x['Location']).title(), axis=1)
out['Legacy Location'] = np.where(out['Location'].isna(), 'Blank',
                                  np.where(out['Location'] != out['Location_v2'], out['Location'], ''))
out = out.drop(['Location name', 'Location'], axis=1)
out.rename(columns = {'Location_v2':'Location'}, inplace = True)
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

[image]

Comment: I had to remove duplicates after the merge but worked, thank you so much!